# Should the "please accept an answer to your question" reminder be more visible?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If I go to my profile, questions tab, I find that I forgot to accept an answer with a friendly reminder "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?".

But I consider this important enough to be moved to a part of my profile that is more visible.

What is the reason this is buried under questions, instead of being more visible, like a counter in the page profile?

Comment: Probably because there's no obligation to accept any answer. Besides, there might not be any, or at least no acceptable one. Anyway, nagging is bad and repels users.

Comment: @Deduplicator, a counter is hardly a nagging repelling device and I believe we all know that answers don't need to be marked.

Comment: In that case, shall questions without any answers count? Shall question without upvoted answers count? Shall there be any timed cut-off?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I know I'm late here, but are you saying that an automated system cannot check whether there're answers in a question, or whether any answers have been up-voted, and so on? It can. There being "no obligation" is not a good reason to let newbies forget about it and they should learn [what to do when someone answers their question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Personally, I think it should be done for users with low-enough reputation while they learn to use the site.

Comment: @ray: No, any automated system cannot determine whether accepting any of the existing answers (yet) is a good idea.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I agree with you, but I think you misunderstand my comment, which is slightly different from the OP. SO automatically notifies you when you have messages in your Inbox, etc. Similarly, any automated system can check if there're any up-voted answers that have not been accepted in any given question and *suggest* the OP go there and *consider* accepting one if any works out. It could be done after determining the OP's reputation is "low-enough"; any automated system can check that.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It's not about determining the quality of responses; it's about those that forget their questions after they get the responses they wanted and leave everyone else hanging.

Comment: I was going to post a similar question but thought it may be better to put it here.  In addition to the above examples, with agreeing on the last comments by @code_dredd, accepting an answer also helps to highlight quality answers for people who have similar questions later.