# Teaching new users how to accept an answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, new-users

This keeps coming up time and time again. I answer someone's question, they upvote it and say thanks, but they don't accept the answer. I see many other questions answered by other users that never get accepted either. These questions stay 'unanswered' forever, even though they're not. It skews SO's statistics and makes it harder to browse unanswered questions.

I have a few proposals that could help deal with the issue. Some of these proposals have been mentioned before, but I think the answers to them are unsatisfactory.

- When the question owner upvotes an answer, show a *modal dialog* or a *popup* balloon that either...

  - simply reminds them how to use the tick button; or
  - explicitly asks them if the answer answered their question, with Yes/No buttons. If they choose Yes, then automatically mark as accepted.
- For existing questions that have upvoted answers, none of which have been accepted, send out a one-time inbox notification and/or an email to remind users to go back and check them, so they can accept one if applicable. This could potentially help clean up tonnes of old questions, provided the users are still active.

  - [Not getting Acceptance for correct answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345026/534406)
  - [Are we allowed to ask/remind the OP to accept answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262209/534406)
  - [Feature Request: "WAKE UP and accept my answer please"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50452/158692)
  - [Dealing with novice users who fail to choose a best answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107554/158692)

I welcome more suggestions from you guys, as well as your experiences with prior discussions on this matter.

**For avoidance of doubt, I am not suggesting that users be forced to accept answers! These suggestions are supposed to aid in the legitimate Q&A process.**

---

Other Related topics:

- [Should the "please accept an answer to your question" reminder be more visible?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266726/534406)
- [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8692/158692) (the top two answers are very interesting)
- [How do we prod users who have answered their own questions to post an answer and accept it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93129/158692)

---

Edited to add Aurora0001's link to [all the many feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3669?lq=1) similar to mine, that have all been shot down without people actually reading the question and thinking about the problem.

**When is the Stack Exchange team going to admit they can do better to help get proper closure on questions?** It's in everyone's best interests to get them properly accepted.

I must also say that I don't agree with all of the questions that show up in those results. I don't think there's a need for auto-acceptance.

Comment: For what it's worth, the "community accept" feature request is so heavily downvoted because it's [such a common request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3669?lq=1) and is duplicated many times on Meta.SE and Meta SO. (that link is all the questions on Meta.SE linked to or closed as duplicate of the initial "community accept" feature request)

Comment: Meh.... some will accept (usually users who are not new) and some won't, and just like down-votes, it's best to simply accept that this happens and move on.

Comment: I think you can _just tell the user_ that the answer the asker finds useful should be accepted. This has happened to me several times, and I just told them this _as a fact_ and provided a link to the Help Center. After that, people usually accept the most upvoted answer.

Comment: I have a few standing unanswered questions swith positive upvoted answers but none of them actually completely answered my question. In other words, there's a reason they are not accepted. Auto accept would be a bad and irritating feature. Just not worth it.

Comment: A green check mark means that the answer solved the OP's problem and only the OP can tell us that's the case. An up vote only means that an answer was useful. It might be reasonable for the site to show a new user how to accept an answer on their first question, but it should only happen the one time.

Comment: *makes it harder to browse unanswered questions* You can always search for questions with zero answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano

Comment: FWIW I've had answers accepted more than a year after they were written. There is nothing wrong with being patient :)

Comment: So why do you care if answers are marked as accepted or not? All that means is that it solved OPs problem, not that the unmarked answers are not useful.

Comment: @Aurora0001 If it's been asked so many times, then maybe... just maybe, that means someone should actually consider there's an issue and implement one of the suggested solutions.

Comment: @SandPiper I'm not saying anyone should be forced to accept an answer that doesn't solve the problem. I'm saying some people genuinely don't know how to use SO and need an extra prompt.

Comment: On the other hand, we should probably discourage users from pressuring new users into accepting their answers quickly; I see this happen a lot; it's clearly meant to get the answer accepted before anyone else comes along with a better answer.

Comment: @m69 Agreed. The notification would probably be sent out after an answer receives 2+ votes and/or after a few days.

Comment: Indeed. I don't mind people being reminded to "please accept the answer you found most useful", but unfortunately I see a lot of "please accept my answer", sometimes within 15 minutes of the question being posted.

Comment: As a moderator, I *really* don't want to be able to accept answers. Would mean a whole bunch of consideration (and debate on when that power should be used) that currently is a quick 'declined - we can't do that'.

Comment: *The notification would probably be sent out after an answer receives 2+ votes* That implies the OP should be accepting an answer based on its usefulness to *other* people, which isn't what it's for.

Comment: The simple solution here is to remove the "accepted answer" status completely.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN I think the issue *has* been considered very frequently, but the downsides of most of the suggested solutions outweigh the benefits. For example, voting to accept an answer is just duplicating functionality from upvotes, and having moderators do it forces them to make decisions where they may not be knowledgeable. [Users have never been required to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345027/6650102), so a system to accept for them would seem unnecessary.

Comment: I occasionally add the following comment to a question that I have answered and that then has no updates for months:  Has your question been answered? If not then please `[edit]` it to make it clearer. If it has been answered then please read about `[accepting answers]`(http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @yannis Removing that feature will probably drastically reduce the initiative of many users to answer to a new users questions (as they can't neither upvote). This won't be necessary a good thing. Though it will also drastically reduce the initiative from the rep-ladies-of-the-night to answer all the dupes too which will make me very very happy. In either-way, this doesn't look like a straightforward decision to me.

Comment: [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10187977/anoop-deshpande) asked 21 questions and 14 are answered with one or multiple answers. But he not accepted a single answer. Some people just throws their problem without spending time while writing question and won't do follow up's. If someone spends time to answer but he gets no follow up's from OP. Can we expect a user identification? Zero accepted user icon? I don't think I am wrong.

Comment: @Undo In light of a warning I got recently from the moderator team for educating new users about the possibility to upvote/accept answers, please confirm Kamil Kilczewski's suggestion leads to warnings/suspensions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The issue in your case was you were posting comments about this *on nearly every answer you've posted* (and you answer a lot of questions). Moderators remove comments asking for that from any user, so you were creating needless work for us. That is why we asked you to stop.

Comment: @Machavity Yes, but you did not have to, as I remove them myself. BTW, I removed **all** my remaining comments of this kind after your warning so that you did not have to do that any longer (about 58 I believe).

Answer (score 15):

The consensus is that despite repeated requests to do something about the acceptance status of a question, no further action is required. I think that the important take-away from this discussions is that answer acceptance **is not that important**. It's just a special kind of vote, one among many.

In SO and other SE sites, what the community uses to signal quality and usefulness is the aggregate of community votes. A question is not *"open"* or lacking *"closure"* because the OP didn't accept a particular answer.

The green check mark sends a warm and fuzzy feeling to the answerer (and a few precious points); but is not really that useful to determine that an answer is *better* than another for future visitors. After all, in many cases (although not always) the OP would be the least qualified to determine which answer is the best one.

In that vein, even if this and similar concerns were raised in the past, this and every other time the vast majority spoke against them; because any effort in the direction of improving the acceptance ratio for answers seems ill suited.

Please, do not take this personally. Being on the minority opinion is not always easy. Your concern is valid, but you just voiced a variation of a oft repeated theme, that most of the community feels is done with, and disagrees with.

Comment: There are several situations, where there is only one answer posted. And there are some users which notoriously do not accept answers. As long as the green checkmark gives reputation, one should at least indicate that the user of the question did not accepted a single answer in the past.

Comment: If answer acceptance is not that important then why not just remove +15point bonus to accepted answer? You showed also that essentially the answer acceptance is bad and misleading thing because (often) OP is the least qualified to determine which answer is the best one - so may be good idea is to just remove answer acceptance by OP?

Comment: @Kamil If you search, you'll see that **many** users have campaigned for making accepted answers less prominent (e.g. unpinning them the top of the answer list). But that's a completely different subject. Seach for those discussions and add your input there.

Answer (score 2):

As is written [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/860099) you can inform new users (not aware that something like answer "accept" or votes exists) by comment their question in following way as example:

> You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check
>   button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any
>   author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

**this way of informing is very effective** - just try. I also heard from one person:

*"have seen people baiting OP to up vote and accept telling him it's free 5 point"*

so by right informing in comment you also protect new users from that kind of deception.

However, convincing the community to automate this process will be rather impossible for various reasons (as you saw on comments below your question).

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Comments like these are considered *noise* and will be removed by moderators if flagged. Please do not post comments like these on a frequent basis, as it simply adds to the work of the moderation team. If you do post them, please remove them yourself after a short time (if you don't get an accept in short order, it's unlikely to happen). If you post these too often, we will ask you to stop.

Answer (score -11):

I'm one of sinners, I've spent hors and hours and looked EVERYWHERE on Google and YouTube on how to accept an answer. No luck, I simply can't locate the accept button anywhere, I feel so dumb and I've stopped using Stack Overflow because I'm afraid to make people angry.

Comment: Strange because you have accepted some answers on your questions: i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346139

Comment: Maybe you are trying to accept [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72845418/how-to-set-full-height-in-grid-template-row#comment128665471_72845418)? See [There is no checkmark for me to accept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380134/there-is-no-checkmark-for-me-to-accept-an-answer)

Comment: My google search did bring up https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and that has acceptance guidance with extra links to the FAQ. I'm wondering why that result didn't turn up in your Google search.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to accept an answer on someone else's question? You can only accept answers on your own questions.

Comment: Re *"I've stopped using Stack Overflow because I'm afraid to make people angry"*: You are not at all obliged to accept an answer. Don't be scared off by reputation points addicts. Recent related meta post: *[Rule proposal: comments asking for accepts and votes shall no longer be allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418169/)*