# What should we do when two answers are of equal quality?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, accepted-answer

I just saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73286722/concatenate-3d-numpy-arrays-that-have-been-chunked/), and my answer and another person's are both correct. If I were the OP, I wouldn't know which to accept. How should we accept answers in this situation?

Comment: Just because both answers are correct doesn't make them "of equal quality". Acceptance is entirely up to OP's discretion, and there is no requirement to accept an answer at all. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel but both of the answers consist of just code

Comment: FWIW, I think your answer is better written (I'm not sure offhand which offers the better *solution*). You include some meaningful explanation and a relevant documentation link.

Comment: Both answers are correct but not equally helpful. The solution with `np.hstack` from `np.dstack`s is not trivially applicable (and 2x slower) for the actual use case (grid of 16x16 chunks of 3D arrays) mentioned.

Comment: If there is absolutely no other consideration distinguishing merit, reward the person with lower reputation.

Comment: @NickCox Askers should not accept an answer based on the answer authors' reputation; please don't listen to such suggestions. Answers should be accepted based on which solution the asker ended up using or most led the asker to their desired goal, or if a theoretical question which solution provided the best (in the author's opinion) explanation or code.

Comment: There is emphasis almost everywhere on the OP's discretion in accepting an answer and a _recommendation_ that they reward merit. It's too rule-obsessed to insist that other criteria might not apply and a tad discourteous to urge "don't listen" to other suggestions.  To repeat, _if there is no perception of differing merit_, then go for the person most in need of, and most likely to appreciate, the small boost in reputation. I have 33K and am really delighted if good people in my small corner of SO with more like 300 or 3K can get the extra reputation for their work if their answer is as good.

Comment: @TylerH in essence it's bookkeeping, not a reward system... I can't believe that we're here again to be honest. This is really basic stuff.

Comment: @NickCox Nobody "needs" reputation; that's not what it's for. You're not doling out charity here. The only reason there are _people_ involved with writing answers on SO at all is because there is no AI sufficiently advanced to ask and answer all questions. It's not about _us_, it's about the _repository of Q&A_. Basing your actions as a user on _who_ wrote a post, no matter how noble you imagine it, is wrong and antithetical to the ethos of the site. So yes, *absolutely* "don't listen" to such suggestions (or make them), please.

Comment: @TylerH You disagree with my suggestion given the question of what to do if questions are of equal merit, but you don’t need to be hectoring  or patronizing about it. I too have experience and views about SO and really don’t need an explanation that people are needed to make it work.

Comment: Need = some people need extra reputation to get to where they have privileges to do what their work deserves, e.g. vote, edit, close.

Comment: X gets two equally good answers from A and B and decides to accept  that from A as A has the lower reputation. This is being condemned as a thought crime: they are thinking the wrong way about SO! Would tossing a coin be a better idea? Or not accepting either answer?

Comment: @NickCox No one "deserves" to have any privileges (privileges, not rights) here. That's not how the site works.This is not patronizing or hectoring, I am simply explaining that you are mistaken. And who said anything about thought crimes? I don't care what you _think_, only what you _do_, especially when it is telling other people to do the wrong thing. Yes, tossing a coin would be better. If two answers provide the exact same solution with the exact same explanation (rather unlikely) and you use one of them, pick one at random, or if you _must_ discern, pick the one that was posted first.

Comment: "*I too have experience and views about SO and really don’t need an explanation that people are needed to make it work.*" I don't take anything for granted here; when a user suggests we start voting based on the author rather than based on the content, I have to assume they don't know how the site works. Someone with experience on SO *should* know that we vote based on content, not based on the person.

Comment: We’ve exchanged views. The idea that random choice beats other criteria is ludicrous in my view. I will let others judge on tone and logic.

Comment: If anyone is following, and confused, let me repeat my original suggestion: "If there is absolutely no other consideration distinguishing merit, reward the person with lower reputation" Nothing more than that.

Comment: But why, @NickCox? Why not choose the perceived gender of the author as the tie-breaker? Or their geographical location? Or some other arbitrary criterion? Because that's a slippery slope and implies a very serious misunderstanding of the goals of this site. The goal of this site is not to earn reputation. That's simply not a good standard.

Comment: @Cody Gray I don't think that the goal of this site is to earn reputation. How do you infer that? Ir is disturbing how hostile some can be over a small suggestion on what to do **when answers are of equal merit**. The assertion that I "don't know how the site works" was uncalled for.  By all means mock words you don't like such as "deserve" but -- subject to editing, voting and moderation -- there is still some freedom of thought here. I vote up and down depending on what I think deserves it and I don't mind if at the margin some OPs show a little caprice over which answer is accepted.

Comment: @CodyGray I think there is confusion here among what *equal merit* really means, and it is, I should say, *not really possible* unless deemed by the OP that both have good explanations and code e.g. - but in my opinion, I think the OP should choose the answer he/she likes best in this scenario (Is this correct?)

Comment: @NickCox People disagreeing with you or pointing out that your suggestions about using the site are incorrect is not "hostile", "uncalled for", or "mocking". Please set aside the notion that this is personal or about _you_, just like posts and their scores are not about the _people posting them_ or _their reputation_. That seems to be the root of the misunderstanding at play here: it's the content, not the person behind it, that matters on Stack Overflow. Separate the idea from the person, whether it's an answer on main or a discussion here on Meta.

Comment: @DialFrost Yes, that is correct; the asker should choose whichever answer they believe is the best answer in their scenario. *Typically* (but not *always*) this means the answer they end up using/applying to their problem.

Comment: The title of this thread remains "What should we do when two answers are of equal quality?" and so just repeating the advice to choose the better answer is not addressing the question. The advice to anyone who uses another criterion as a tie-breaker is to keep quiet about their reason, as someone may be watching and wanting to chastise their incorrect attitude.

Comment: Depends @NickCox, 2 answers of equal quality might not mean the OP does not prefer one answer over the other (maybe due to one being easier to use or simpler, or best the OP just likes it better)

Comment: @DialFrost Not for me to disapprove of such choices. That's my point too: the OP has discretion,

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would accept your answer if I was the OP of the question.

It is simpler since it only relies on one method call, whereas the other one has three calls.

It also has the most upvotes.

But acceptance is up to the OP. He could accept either one or none at all. On Stack Overflow it is considered bad practice to try to influence OP to accept any answer.